# suggestion needed for running a model in a NB1 while data is imported from NB2

Tags: notebooks, code-request

I want to iteratively run a set of scenarios. There are two notebooks `NB1` and `NB2`. The former includes the following system of 2 equations, and the latter includes data and parameter specifications for scenarios. `NB1` is:

```
a X1 + b Y1 == A1;
c X1 + d Y1 == B1;
```

where `{A1, B1}` is the set of constants, and `{a, b, c, d}` is the set of parameters calculated in `NB2`.

In the notebook `NB2`, I keep the data and parameters (scenarios):

```
benchmarkData = {A1=3, B1=7, a=2, b=9, c=5, d=4};
scenario[i]   = {A1=1, B1=0, a=1, b=8, c=5, d=4};
```

In `NB1`, I also created a matrix of 8 by 6 in order to store the solutions from i=6 scenarios. The first column is reserved for storing the solution from i=1 in the order of `sol[1] = {X1, Y1, A1, B1, a, b, c, d}`. I first run `NB2` to define `benchmarkData` and `scenario[i]`, and then go to `NB1` to `Get["file director of NB2"]` the defined benchmark and scenario variables into `NB1` and run the model. When the solution is obtained, store it to the first column of the scenario matrix created in `NB1`. I repeat the same procedure for each new scenario: design a new scenario in `NB2`, go to `NB1` to run the model and store the solution in the 2nd column of the matrix, etc.

I know how to do this operation in a single notebook by using:

```
While[z<7, {the model and the matrix}; z++]
```

but I could not do the same iteration using two separate notebooks. This is a simple version of a very big model with a large dataset. That is why I had to divide the `code` into two notebooks to iteratively run the scenarios and get a matrix of solutions.

I tried several ways to achieve the task such as creating an index `z` in `NB2` and store the solution in `NB1` with an indexed variable but it did not work because the code always kept the very last scenario run not the earlier ones.

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I am likely missing the point, but why not store the scenarios (NB2) in a simple text file, one record per line.

```
3 7 2 9 5 4
1 0 1 8 5 4
```

You can then read the whole file from NB1 as a list, an assign values to variables in a loop.

```
a X1 + b Y1 == A1;
c X1 + d Y1 == B1;

data = ReadList[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "dataN2.txt"}],
    Number, RecordLists -> True, 
   RecordSeparators -> {"\n", "\r\n", "\r"}];

z = 1;
While[z <= Length[data],
 A1 = data[[z, 1]];
 B1 = data[[z, 2]];
 a = data[[z, 3]];
 b = data[[z, 4]];
 c = data[[z, 5]];
 d = data[[z, 6]];

 Echo[Solve[a X1 + b Y1 == A1 && c X1 + d Y1 == B1, {X1, Y1}]];

 z++;
 ]
```

Here are the results for these two entries:

```
{{X1->51/37,Y1->1/37}}

{{X1->-(1/9),Y1->5/36}}
```

Comment: One of the reasons why I like to run an iterative procedure is that I have many different scenarios and I did not want to keep all these scenarios in a separate text file. Instead, I just want to change few parameters in NB1 and run the model in NB2 and see the results immediately in the predefined table. Another reason is that I wanted to store the results from each scenario as a column vector of an output matrix created in NB2. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the above problem.

When you add the following `code` at the end of NB2, each time you run the model with a different parameter set, the results are saved in a file created by `OpenAppend[...]`. New runs are appended to the previous set of results.

```
(*First create a file to keep the results obtained from each run*)

ESTgrowth = FileNameJoin[{"directory to keep the file", "ESTgrowth"}];
open = OpenAppend[ESTgrowth];
Write[open, newsolution];  (*`newsolution` is the results from a model run that you want to keep.*)
Close[open];
EST = FilePrint[ESTgrowth]
(*use DeleteFile[ESTgrowth] to delete the file from the   
directory concerned*)
```

This is a very convenient way of running a given model for different parameters without making any change in the model variables. Moreover, the results are nicely kept in a separate file that can be used in other calculations without needing to run the model again.